# How do the $l^p$ topologies on sequences relate to the product topology?

Tags: general-topology, functional-analysis, soft-question

This is a soft (because not fully specified) question.

Let (as usual) $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ be the set of real sequences $(x_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}}$. This is the cartesian product of $\omega$-many copies of $\mathbb{R}$, so if we endow $\mathbb{R}$ with its usual topology, then $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ can be given the product topology. (If $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ is interpreted as the space of maps $\mathbb{N}\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ via $(x_n)\mapsto (n\mapsto x_n)$, then endowing it with the compact-open topology [assuming the discrete topology on $\mathbb{N}$] does the same thing, it seems to me.)

Meanwhile, for $1\leq p \leq \infty$, let (as usual) $l^p$ be the subset of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ consisting of $p$th-power-summable sequences, i.e., those satisfying

$$ \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |x_n|^p < \infty.$$

(For $p=\infty$ the condition is instead that $(x_n)$ is bounded.) Usually $l^p$ is viewed as a Banach space with the $l^p$-norm

$$ \|(x_n)\|_p := \left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}} |x_n|^p\right)^{1/p}.$$

(For $p=\infty$, the norm is instead $\sup_n |x_n|$.) My question is this:

**What is known about the relationship between the topology on $l^p$ coming from the $l^p$ norm, vs. the subspace topology induced by the product topology on $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$?**

For example:

- It seems to me that both topologies will induce the same topology on a finite-dimensional subspace of $l^p$; but this is not saying much.
- It seems to me that the open unit ball with respect to the $l^p$ norm is not an open set of the subspace topology on $l^p\subset \mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, because any open set in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ contains sequences with coordinates that are $>1$, and some of them are in $l^p$. (Am I thinking about this right?) So, is it the case that the $l^p$ norm topology is strictly finer than the subspace topology coming from $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$? Or are there open sets in the latter that are not open in the former? If so, what's an example?

**Context:** This section can be ignored, it adds no mathematical content to the question. I include it only for readers who are curious why I am asking this.

The above question was stimulated by the following meandering and undisciplined, but to me provocative, train of thought:

1. The closed unit ball in a Hilbert space with a countably infinite Hilbert space basis such as $l^2$ is famously not compact; so undoubtedly the "unit cube" is also not compact. But Tychonoff's theorem says that the product of an $\mathbb{N}$-indexed collection of unit intervals is compact. Huh.
2. Oh wait. If I take the unit cube in $l^2$ to be sequences $(x_n)\in l^2$ such that each $x_i$ is in $[0,1]$, then the cartesian product of $\mathbb{N}$-many $[0,1]$'s is actually strictly bigger than this! In particular, $(1,1,\dots)$ is not in $l^2$. (In fact, only the finitely supported $0,1$-sequences are in $l^p$ for any $p<\infty$.) So there is a proper subset of $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ that is in $l^2$! I wonder what this subset "looks like".
3. Meanwhile, the entirety of $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ *is* in $l^\infty$! More precisely, there is a natural bijection of $[0,1]^\mathbb{N}$ (the compact space with the product topology) with the subset of $l^\infty$ satisfying $0\leq x_n\leq 1$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Is it a homeomorphism?

Comment: Your second bullet point, starting with *It seems to me...*, doesn't make much  sense. The statement *any open set in $\mathbb R$ contains sequences with boundedly big coordinates* is just false: the interval $(-1,+1)$ is an open set in $\mathbb R$, and for every sequence $(x_n)$ contained in that interval, we have $|x_n| < 1$, so the coordinates of that sequence are bounded.

Comment: The product topology is weaker than the $\ell_p$ norm topology, as the projections are $\| \cdot \|_p$ continuous, and the inclusion is strict.


Yes, the open ball of $\ell_p$ is not open in product topology. I would show that the complement is not closed, by consider $x_n^{i}= δ_{in}$, ie the usual Schauder Basis

Comment: @LeeMosher Sorry, I meant "...any open set in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$..."; I'll edit.

Comment: @EvangelopoulosPhoevos - I've grown in my conviction that the argument given in the OP (hat the $\ell^p$-open ball is not open in the product topology) works, but I would like to see it your way too. Why does the Schauder basis show the complement is not closed?

Comment: That makes more sense, but now I'll point out that for $p \ge 1$ and for $(x_n) \in \mathbb R^{\mathbb N}$ the series $\sum_{n=1}^\infty |x_n|^p$ converges only if the sequence $|x_n|^p$ converges to $0$ only if the sequence $(x_n)$ converges to zero only if the sequence $(x_n)$ is bounded (of course two of these three "only if" statements are not reversible).

Comment: @LeeMosher Thank you for pressing on my precision. I see I really didn't say what I meant at all. I meant that for a given prespecified bound and a given open subset in $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$, there are sequences belonging to that open subset that have entries that exceed that bound. In particular, any open subset of $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ contains an $\ell^p$ sequence that has an entry of absolute value $>1$, so that sequence does not belong to the open unit ball in $\ell^p$. In particular, the open unit ball in $\ell^p$ cannot be an open set with respect to the product topology. I'll edit.

Comment: @BenBlum-Smith Let $A= \{ x \mid \|x\|_p \ge 1\}$ and let $x_n(i) = 1$ if $i=n$ and zero elsewhere. Then  $x_n \in A$, but their pointwise limit, namely, the sequence $0$, does not belong to $A$. This shows that $A$ is not closed

Comment: @EvangelopoulosPhoevos - Thanks so much, perfect. (I think I didn't realize that pointwise convergence of a sequence of sequences implies convergence in the product topology. I see why now, though.)

Comment: It's known that $\ell^p$ and $\mathbb{R}^\mathbb{N}$ are homeomorphic

Answer (score 1):

The $\ell^P(\mathbb{N})$ is much finner than the product topology, which was already mentioned in comments. But a curious fact that can  be useful in some moments is that any open set of $\ell^P(\mathbb{N})$ is the product of an $\mathbb{R}^n$ open set with an $\ell^P(\mathbb{N})$ open set.